# Confusion on Racket Function

Tags: racket

I am looking to create this function that takes a number and returns a string that gives that number as an item quantity. So far, I cannot think of a way to transfer this number into a string, nor come up with a clause that can change the grammar from 1 item to 2 item(s).

```
(check-expect (package-quantity 1) "1 item")
(check-expect (package-quantity 2) "2 items")

(define (package-quantity q)
  (
```

Answer (score 0):

When producing quantities for the human reader, there could also be special cases:

```
;language: Advanced Student

(check-expect (package-quantity 1) "1 item")
(check-expect (package-quantity 2) "1 pair")
(check-expect (package-quantity 3) "3 items")

(: package-quantity (Natural -> String))
   
(define (package-quantity q)
  ;; produce description of quantity, with special cases
  (cond
    [(zero? q) "nothing" ]
    [(= q 2) "1 pair" ]
    [(= q 12) "1 dozen" ]
    [else (string-append
           (number->string q)
           (cond
             [(= q 1) " item" ]
             [else " items" ])) ]))
```